# Declaring a struct which works with an array in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

The program is supposed to calculate the magnitude of vectors and then print out the results. I can manage all of this work but I am having trouble actually declaring the struct.

The program will prompt the user for the number of vectors they would like to store.

so I left my struct array un-allocated and I will come back later with malloc()/free()

but here is what I am trying to do

```
struct vector *array
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}
```

x.y.z being the points of the vector, I am assuming each element of array will contain x,y,z but this is not working when I compile it gives me errors of "," "asm" not found before { so I put an = like this

```
struct vector *array=
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
    }
```

it then gives me expression before double not found

What am I doing wrong??

Again if not clarified.

I am trying to have the user enter the number of vectors to be used which then that number will be used within malloc to allocate memory to the struct array which I am assuming each element of the array will contain x.y.z

New to structs so help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct vector
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct vector *array;
```

Now array is pointer to a struct vector and you can create instances of it by allocating required memory using `malloc()` and assign value to the struct fields for each instance.

Like

```
array = malloc(sizeof(struct vector) *n ); /* n = size inputted by user */
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  array[i].x = <someval>;
  array[i].y = <someval>;
  array[i].z = <someval>;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, now we have a pointer to struct vector. So will each element of that array contain x,y,z and if I need to access each of those I would just do something like this array[1].x or array[1].y

Comment: asked the question right as you updated yours haha thank you alot for the concise and timely response

Comment: almost when the user enters the value for n and then the for loop is created based off of that value, how would you successively store the vector values entered by the user something like fgets(buffer,100,stdin) and then use sscanf?

Comment: @Superman Please ask this part as a separate question IMO. Inside the `for` loop you can use `scanf("%lf",&a[i].x);` to scan values to your structure members. Similarly you should scan values for `y` and `z` also